# Timeout structure in Go

Tags: go, timeout, storage, structure

I'm looking for a storage with the ability of storing expiring data. I mean, a structure where you could specify the data to be stored and a timeout, and where that value would be removed after some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this for caching, consider using [cache2go](https://github.com/muesli/cache2go):

```
cache := cache2go.Cache("c")
val := struct{x string}{"This is a test!"}
cache.Add("valA", 5*time.Second, &val)
```

As cache2go is for caching it operates on memory alone but you can specify a data loading routine to lazily load a missing value for a given key. The data loader can be utilized to
[load the value from disk](https://github.com/muesli/cache2go/blob/master/examples/dataloader/dataloader.go):

```
cache.SetDataLoader(func(key interface{}) *cache2go.CacheItem {
    val := loadFromDisk()
    item := cache2go.CreateCacheItem(key, 0, val)
    return &item
})
```

[go-cache](http://patrickmylund.com/projects/go-cache/) supports this as well and supports loading cached items from disk:

> func (c *Cache) Set(k string, x interface{}, d time.Duration)
>       Adds an item to the cache, replacing any existing item. If the duration is 0,
>       the cache's default expiration time is used. If it is -1, the item never
>       expires.
>
> func (c *Cache) Save(w io.Writer) error
>       Writes the cache's items (using Gob) to an io.Writer. Returns an error if
>       the serialization fails, e.g. because there are unserializable objects like
>       channels in the cache.
>
> func (c *Cache) Load(r io.Reader) error
>       Adds (Gob-serialized) cache items from an io.Reader, excluding any items that
>       already exist in the current cache.

Comment: Thanks nemo, I think it could solve my problem. I'll take a look to it.